# How to get a data between vertical bar using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

Table DATA:

```
id   text
1    CLARE|FEMALE|PRESIDENT 
2    SCARLET|FEMALE|MANAGER   
3    FRANK|MALE|ANALYST   
...
```

What I need to do is to get all data between **vertical bar** and put it in my variables(for insert to another table),

here what i tried :

```
DECLARE
    v_NAME varchar2(100);    
    v_GENDER nvarchar2(100); 
    v_POSITION nvarchar2(100);   

    CURSOR c1
    IS 
        SELECT * 
        FROM DATA
        ORDER BY id;

BEGIN
    FOR x IN c1 LOOP
        v_NAME := REGEXP_SUBSTR(x.TEXT_NOTE, '[^|]+', 1, 1);
        v_GENDER := REGEXP_SUBSTR(x.TEXT_NOTE, '[^|]+', 1, 2);
        v_POSITION := REGEXP_SUBSTR(x.TEXT_NOTE, '[^|]+', 1, 3);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_NAME ,v_GENDER ,v_POSITION); --test
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Obviously I'm not doing this right as it doesn't work. Can somebody suggest a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there are two points to fix in your attempt :

- In your LOOP you are referring to column "x.TEXT_NOTE" whereas it should be column "TEXT" from your table DATA.
- You need to change that output line DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_NAME ,v_GENDER ,v_POSITION) by DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_NAME||', '||v_GENDER||', '||v_POSITION)

```sql
CREATE TABLE DATA_TO_SPLIT (id, text) as (
select 1, 'CLARE|FEMALE|PRESIDENT' from dual union all
select 2, 'SCARLET|FEMALE|MANAGER' from dual union all
select 3, 'FRANK|MALE|ANALYST'  from dual
)
;
```

```sql
DECLARE
    v_NAME varchar2(100);    
    v_GENDER nvarchar2(100); 
    v_POSITION nvarchar2(100);   

    CURSOR c1
    IS 
        SELECT * 
        FROM DATA_TO_SPLIT
        ORDER BY id;

BEGIN
    FOR x IN c1 LOOP
        v_NAME := REGEXP_SUBSTR(x.TEXT, '[^|]+', 1, 1);
        v_GENDER := REGEXP_SUBSTR(x.TEXT, '[^|]+', 1, 2);
        v_POSITION := REGEXP_SUBSTR(x.TEXT, '[^|]+', 1, 3);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_NAME||', '||v_GENDER||', '||v_POSITION); --test
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The string_split function should work.

```
SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT('CLARE|FEMALE|PRESIDENT', '|')
```

Comment: Hi Martin. This is an question of Oracle DB which does not have such a predefined function.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed no problem seems with the current code except

- the typo which needs column name conversion from `text_note` to
  `text`
- and adding an Insert statement for a presumed table (namely
  **data2**) is missing
- Btw, current `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`s syntax is wrong

So, use the following code :

```
DECLARE
  v_name     VARCHAR2(100);
  v_gender   NVARCHAR2(100);
  v_position NVARCHAR2(100);

  CURSOR c1 IS
  SELECT *
    FROM data     
   ORDER BY id;

BEGIN
  FOR x IN c1 
  LOOP
    v_name     := TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(x.text, '[^|]+', 1, 1));
    v_gender   := TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(x.text, '[^|]+', 1, 2));
    v_position := TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(x.text, '[^|]+', 1, 3));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_name||' - '||v_gender||' - '||v_position); 
    INSERT INTO data2 
    VALUES(v_name,v_gender,v_position);
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

where `TRIM()` function stands for removing potential leading and trailing whitespaces

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5a61f55fc2b48d7cb12e6143e83ae25d)</kbd>

Comment: i completely forgot about DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE's syntax really ,thanks so much